# Amazon S3 sync to local folder - Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am working with files that are stored on S3. Because there could be a lot of files, classic list will return only 1000 files that are on S3, but I need only new ones to be downloaded to local folder. This could be done by sync between local folder and S3.

I know that this is possible through amazon cli, but is this possible to be done through Amazon Java SDK. I tried to search it and read documentation, but I was not successful. I found that there is some version in PHP SDK ([PHP version](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2W9JAA7RXVOXA/Syncing-Data-with-Amazon-S3)), so is there similar version for Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java SDK certainly provides sufficient capabilities to create a Java application that will synchronize a local directory with an S3 bucket. I do not know of a high-level API call that you can make that encapsulates exactly this functionality, but it can be built out of the existing API methods. `TransferManager.downloadDirectory()` will recursively download files, but it will not skip those that already exist.

This should be easy to build:

1. Using normal Java APIs, get information about the existing local files.
2. Using the S3 Java SDK, get information about the existing S3 objects in the bucket.
3. Compare the two sets of files and download the new ones.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of that, but it is not what I have in mind. In Amazon Cli there is command sync that will download files that are not in current folder and also you could add pattern and similar and I was hoping that something similar could be done with SDK.